# How do I connect a WIX website to an external mariadb or mysql database

Tags: mysql, mariadb, content-management-system, velo

I want to display information on a table on a WIX website and I'm using WIX developer mode and this information is coming from a database that's outside the WIX database structure.

I tried creating a collection on WIX but that does not solve the problem so I really need a database structure that's not provided by WIX.

Comment: What does "information on a table" mean? Like `show create table {tablename}`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to display information from a mariadb server in a table on a wix website I'm trying to know if it can be done on WIX @danblack

Comment: Does [wix's support topic](https://support.wix.com/en/article/velo-integrating-external-databases-with-your-wix-site) about integrating external databases help?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way by going to the packages segment of wix and by adding the nodejs for package for mariadb I accessed it from my .js file in the backend section right there on wix.